# How to implement jquery crossDomain

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Trying to get my html/JS file to read and print firstName from this link:
 http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/demo_ajax_json.js, as trial for something else I want to do.

Received this error: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin, so trying to use crossDomain.

Read this: jquery API but not sure how to implement correctly

My JS code (I know it's off, but no idea how to correct it):

```
var myArray = [];
var jsonArrayObj;
$.ajax{
    crossDomain: true}).done(function(){ 
        $(document).ready(function(){
            myArray = $.getJSON("http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/demo_ajax_json.js", function(result){
                myArray = JSON.parse(myArray);
                console.log(myArray.firstName);
            });
        });
    });
```

I don't understand what function() does in JS either

Comment: Don't you need `dataType: "jsonp"` for that to work?  json != jsonp though.

Comment: Hard to give you a solution, but I can point you there: here is a great overview of the same origin policy you are offending: https://jvaneyck.wordpress.com/2014/01/07/cross-domain-requests-in-javascript/ also the function keyword creates an anonymous callback function to run that block of code upon completion of the get json etc call you are making.

Comment: since there's no cors on the url, it simply wont wont. ever.

Comment: Not possible with the given domain, Try another that implements CORS or JSONP. Side thought... Why is that filename named .js, if it contains json? *because w3schools.*

Comment: This site might be a better place for you to experiment. They provide some simple jQuery examples and the site is CORS/JSONP enabled. [JSONPlaceholder](http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use CORS to access a website unless the website allows you to do so. If CORS was allowed on that endpoint, there would be an HTTP header for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` (or a specific hostname). So the server you are attempting to talk to has to have a header allowing this to happen.

That endpoint works on the [w3schools getJSON() demo page](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_getjson.asp) because the JavaScript is running from the same domain as the XHR target (so CORS is not needed).

More here: [MDN: HTTP access control (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

[JSONP/JSON-P](http://json-p.org/) is an alternative to CORS but that endpoint doesn't appear to support it either (at least not with the typical `callback` querystring key).

Answer (score 0):

Its because of [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). Try to load file locally.

In your code you are using anonymous function. Internet is full of pages to read about javascript functions.

FUNCTIONS:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JavaScript/Anonymous_Functions

If you are not familiar with JS syntax try to take online course to get your head around it.

JAVASCRIPT COURSE:

http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/javascript

Google for more. ;)